# Sending A Fax from a VB.Net program

Tags: vb.net, winforms, fax

I noticed that in Windows 7  there is a Program called Windows Fax and Scan that enables you to send a fax from a computer that has a fax modem.

I would like to do this from within my VB.Net WinForm application. Has anyone done this? Do you have an example you could post or point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Commercial Porduct call FaxMan Jr.